# Removing specific tags that have attributes from html

Tags: tags, html

I want to remove tags from a html file....but only tags with a specific attribute.

For example, I might have the following code:

```
<span class = 'A'>This is the first sentence.</span><span id = 'B'>This is the second sentence</span>
```

I want to remove all occurrences of `<span id = 'B'>` such that the result is as follows

```
<span class = 'A'>This is the first sentence.</span>This is the second sentence
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you give us a better example?

Comment: sorry, the tags were parsed. I use normal text, please see if you can understand

Comment: copy your code in question text area , Select whole code and press ctrl+k .. it wont be parsed

Comment: Please add your **input** and **output** separately. So we can understand better.

Comment: You mean you want this by doing something on the browser? For example clicking on a button? So you need JavaScript. If you want to use jQuery (as a JS library), this can be done: `$('#B').contents().unwrap();`. Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cRGHQ/).